# Accessing a form's tooltip from another class in visual studio (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2015, tooltip

I am quite new to visual studio. Developed previously with vba.

Encountering a problem writing a language translation class.

The language dependent values are stored in a localdb table every row having formname , controlname and controlproperty as wel as a column per language.

The Language class Handles the translations at runtime. For forms I use a Sub FormUpdate(frm as Form) called from the form's load event as FormUpdate(Me) it checks the form's language kept in a custom parameter against the current language and updates the .text property of the controls on the form that are exposing some language specific text (Buttons, Labels, Tabcontrol etc..).

However I could not solve how to access and update the form's Tooltip component from the language class. (in vba it was easy as every control was exposing it's Controltiptext property)

In the form's class you would use MyTooltip.Settooltip(CtrlName,Text) but I could not figure out how to do that from another class (the tooltip component is not part of the form's controls - and I could not figure out nor find info how to do it) ??

Could someone advise pls?

Comment: The `ToolTip` is not a control, hence it's not being part of the `Controls` collection.  The `ToolTip` is a component.  There is a roundabout way to access designer-generated components but it's not something I know off the top of my head.  You could look it up, or the alternative is to access the `ToolTip` via the field generated for all designer-generated components.

Answer (score 0):

I was so focused on finding a similar way to the one I used before that I did not see the easy way to resolve it - not yet enough accustomed to the new environment.

Sure, I am interested in an answer to my question but instead of making it too complicated using external components I'll do it the easy way by overloading the `FormUpdate` sub adding a sub with an extra parameter as Tooltip.